# How to read URL parameters in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am calling a webservice from lightning web component and it respond with a value. This value is appended in the URL. However, when the page start loading I can see the value but it vanishes as soon as page load completes and I cannot see the parameter in the console.log as well.

sCurrentURL is page URL

```
 connectedCallback(){
        //get the parameters of the URL
        let sTempURL = new URL(this.sCurrentURL).searchParams;
        if(this.sCompleteURL == ''){
            this.sCompleteURL = sTempURL.get('code');
        }
        console.log(this.sCompleteURL);
        if(sTempURL.get('code') != null && sTempURL.get('code') != ''){
            this.sAuthCode = sTempURL.get('code');
            getToken({
                sAuthCode : this.sAuthCode
            }).then( () => {refreshApex(this.retreiveTokens)});
        }else{
            //do nothing
        }
    }
```

When trying to use the traditional ways to capture the parameter from url, I get undefined.
I also tried using an api property with same name as the url parameter, but nothing is captured in that too.

Comment: @sfdcfox My URL parameters coming from the external website. I tried with the link provided by you, but it is giving me undefined as value. I am getting value as below:
{"type":"standard__navItemPage","attributes":{"apiName":"SetValues"},"state":{}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to 'namespace' your custom query params or Salesforce will strip them. Try setting `?c__code=xxxx` in your url.

See [this critical update](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_namespace_prefix_cruc_reminder.htm).

Comment: the code response is coming from the different system, we are not setting the code parameters. So, I wouldn't be to set it with the namespace.

Comment: @SFDC then you'll need to reach out to whoever is generating that URL and tell them to generate it with c__ before the query params or they get stripped out by Salesforce. Not much you can do from within the platform.